# How to configure route for port forwarding by Apache Camel?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, mina

Here is the **codec** and **data format** configuration:

```
package com.chorke.boot.jproxy.config;

import org.apache.camel.component.hl7.HL7DataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.component.hl7.HL7MLLPCodec;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:/META-INF/camel/applicationContext-camel.xml"})
public class ApacheCamelConfig {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApacheCamelConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public HL7MLLPCodec hl7codec() {
        HL7MLLPCodec hl7codec = new HL7MLLPCodec();
        hl7codec.setCharset("UTF-8");
        return hl7codec;
    }

    @Bean
    public HL7DataFormat hl7Format() {
        HL7DataFormat hl7Format = new HL7DataFormat();
        return hl7Format;
    }
}
```

Here is the **port forwarding** route:

```
package com.chorke.boot.jproxy.route;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ProxyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private static final Logger log =LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProxyRoute.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("mina2://tcp://0.0.0.0:22210?codec=#hl7codec&sync=true").process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                log.info("Port-Forwarded body:\n {}", body);
            }
        }).to("mina2://tcp://192.168.0.10:22210?codec=#hl7codec&sync=true").end();

        from("mina2://tcp://0.0.0.0:22211?codec=#hl7codec&sync=true").process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                log.info("Port-Forwarded body:\n {}", body);
            }
        }).to("mina2://tcp://192.168.0.11:22211?codec=#hl7codec&sync=true").end();

    }
}
```

The route summery is:

```
============================================
  request                 forwarded
tcp ip:port              tcp ip:port
============================================
0.0.0.0:22210            192.168.0.10:22210
0.0.0.0:22211            192.168.0.11:22211
============================================
```

And it's working fine, it's protocol specific for `MLLP`. But our goal is to route any request regardless their protocol. Lets say it could be handle any kind of request, not limited to `HTTP`, `REST`, `SOAP`, `MLLP`, `SMTP`, `FTP`, `SMB` or etc. Would you please help us to configure port-forwarding route regardless their protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for protocol detection and route port forwarding in Apache Camel. You are better finding some existing product that can do that.